# DOEpy syntax for fractional factorial design in python

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a fractional factorial design in python using the DOEpy package (DOE = Design of experiments). However, I am unable to generate a design that is different from the full factorial design, se below. Can anyone help me? I tried changing the resolution parameter (2) to generate a smaller design matrix but that results in errors.

```
#Full factorial design:
from doepy import build
build.full_fact(
{'Konc':[5,18],
'Temperature':[5, 45],
'Residence Time':[10, 200]}
)
```

And the fractional factorial..

```
#Fractional factorial design:
build.frac_fact_res(
{'Konc':[5, 18],
'Temperature':[5, 45],
'Residence Time':[10, 200]},2) #Changing the 2 to any other value of resolution throws errors.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps @tirtha can help?